# Twilio API / TwiML: Redirect after record won't work

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I'm currently implementing incoming call functionality using Twilio-PHP and TwiML. I'm asking for the callers permission to record the call, which works. However, as soon as I'm starting the recording, nothing after the `<Record>` element is being executed. At this point, I somehow suppose this is expected behavior. Is there any way I can perform `<Redirect>`s etc, while recording? The redirect works when the call is not being recorded.
Here's the PHP file when the user comes back from the recording permission:

```
<?php
    include_once('../../../includes/config.php');
    require_once FULL_DIRECTORY.'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

    $language = 'de-DE';
    $voiceSettings = ['voice' => 'woman', 'language' => $language];

    $response = new VoiceResponse();
    $callerResponse = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST["SpeechResult"]));
    if(($callerResponse == "ja" || $callerResponse == "ya" || $callerResponse == "jo" || $callerResponse == "yes" || $callerResponse == "yea" || $callerResponse == "jaha") && $_REQUEST["Confidence"] > 0.8){
        $response->say('Sie haben der Aufzeichnung zugestimmt.', $voiceSettings);
        $response->record(['action' => '/webhook/twiml/push_recording.php', 'timeout' => 0]);
    }else{
        $response->say('Sie haben der Aufzeichnung nicht zugestimmt. Das Gespräch wird ohne Aufzeichnung fortgesetzt.', $voiceSettings);
    }

    $response->redirect('/webhook/twiml/ask_for_redirect.php', ['method' => 'POST']);
    echo $response;
```

The very last line before the echo (the final redirect) only gets executed when the call is not being recorded.

Any solutions here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Twilio Call Recording Controls.

[Twilio Call Recording Controls is Now Generally Available](https://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-call-recording-controls-is-now-generally-available)